# Get Distinct Values and Converting back into DataTable

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a "result" which is DataTable and I like to get the x distinct values(City) and convert it back to DataTable how do I do this the code below gives me an error

```
 Dim query = (From x In results.AsEnumerable()
                         Select (x.Field(Of String)("City"))).Distinct().CopyToDataTable()
```

so what I want is records of distinct cities I can get that but the problem I am having is converting it back to Datable.

Edited:

I am using "where" in this statement and it does convert to Table(works fine) but not on "select"

```
 Dim results = (From myRow In ds.Tables(1).AsEnumerable()
            Where (myRow.Field(Of String)("xxxx") = xxxx)
                           Select myRow).Distinct().CopyToDataTable()
```

Answer (score 0):

This an example you were looking for?

```
' Bind the System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView object
' to the System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource object.
dataGridView.DataSource = bindingSource

' Fill the DataSet.
Dim ds As New DataSet()
ds.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
' See the FillDataSet method in the Loading Data Into a DataSet topic.
FillDataSet(ds)

Dim orders As DataTable = ds.Tables("SalesOrderHeader")

' Query the SalesOrderHeader table for orders placed 
'  after August 8, 2001.
Dim query = _
    From order In orders.AsEnumerable() _
    Where order.Field(Of DateTime)("OrderDate") > New DateTime(2001, 8, 1) _
    Select order

' Create a table from the query.
Dim boundTable As DataTable = query.CopyToDataTable()

' Bind the table to a System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource object, 
' which acts as a proxy for a System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView object.
bindingSource.DataSource = boundTable
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921.aspx